# Community bulletin is broken on Stack Apps

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackapps, community-bulletin

I've just spotted this on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/); could be *by-design* though.

[image]

Comment: The first thing you post on the bulletin board is "This bulletin board doesn't work!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch.

When I enabled this across the network earlier today, I missed that I needed to explicitly turn it off on Stack Apps.

I've turned it off, so things should be all good now. (:

Comment: She killed it with her pointy stick! Ahhhhh!